# Remove/clear a function on button click in tkinter

Tags: python, function, button, tkinter, label

I have a problem to remove/clear a function on button click in Python.

Here is my function:

```
def my_object():

  label=Label(text="hello")
  label=Label(text="I am feeling lucky")

my_object()

cut_button=Button(command=cut)
```

My problem is that if I press the `cut_button` then the the function `my_object` with two `label`s should be removed/cleared and the screen becomes blank.

Comment: You don't just delete the function to remove labels.

Comment: Sharing your research helps everyone. Tell us what you've tried and why it didn’t meet your needs. This demonstrates that you’ve taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer! See also: [ask]

Comment: Put the labels in a frame, then destroy the frame in `cut()`.  BTW, always specify the parent of widgets when creating them.

Answer (score 0):

I would do something like this:

```
from tkinter import *

class L:
    def __init__(self):
        self.tk = Tk()
        self.l1 = Label(text="hello")
        self.l1.pack()
        self.l2 = Label(text="I am feeling lucky")
        self.l2.pack()

        self.button = Button(command=self.cut)
        self.button.pack()

        self.tk.mainloop()
    def cut(self):
        self.l1.destroy()
        self.l2.destroy()

labels = L()
```

Notice I'm not removing the function, just the labels, saved as attributes of an `labels` object.
Hope that's helpful!